# Unable to loop through multiple pages to scrape data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to move to the next url link (each page has about 20 rows which I need to extract, following which the same needs to be added to the next set of results from the following urls).

There are about 360 urls and I would like to extract data by running through all of them. My code is below. I would like to write them later to a csv file. Any suggestions would be much appreciated as I am new to Python.

```
     from urlparse import urljoin
     import requests
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
     import csv

     base_url = 'http://cricket.inhs.uiuc.edu/edwipweb/FMPro?-db=nvpassoc.fp5&-format=nvp_search_results.htm&-lay=web%20form&-max=20&-findall='
     list_of_rows = []

     next_page = 'http://cricket.inhs.uiuc.edu/edwipweb/FMPro?-db=nvpassoc.fp5&-format=nvp_search_results.htm&-lay=web%20form&-max=20&-skip=20&-findall='

    while True:
      soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(next_page).content)
      soup.findAll('table')[1].findAll('tr')
          for row in soup.findAll('table')[1].findAll('tr'):
             list_of_cells = []
               for cell in row.findAll('p'):
               text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;','')
               list_of_cells.append(text)
             list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

     try:
         next_page = urljoin(base_url, soup.select('/FMPro?-db=nvpassoc.fp5&-format=nvp_search_results.htm&-lay=web%20form&-max=20&-skip=20&-findall=')[1].get('href'))
     except IndexError:
     break


   print list_of_rows

    outfile = open("./trialpage.csv","wb")
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: You need to put your try/except block within your while loop.  You also need to update the next_page each time changing max and skip values

Comment: It is within the while loop. The issue I am having is that it is just printing the first 20 rows in a page and not moving on to the next webpage.

Comment: It isn't in your while loop.  Move it underneath the for loop

Comment: Thanks. I did that. But, should I set the max to the maximum number of values possible? and skip to remain as is? Not sure how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code.  I set up the original url with a variable I called skip.  skip will be incremented by 20 each time through

```
from urlparse import urljoin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

list_of_rows = []

skip = 0
next_page = 'http://cricket.inhs.uiuc.edu/edwipweb/FMPro?-db=nvpassoc.fp5&-format=nvp_search_results.htm&-lay=web%20form&-max=20&-skip=' + str(skip) + '&-findall='
print next_page
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(next_page).content)
    soup.findAll('table')[1].findAll('tr')
    for row in soup.findAll('table')[1].findAll('tr'):
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findAll('p'):
            text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;','')
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

    try:
        skip += 20
        if skip > 300:
            break
        next_page = 'http://cricket.inhs.uiuc.edu/edwipweb/FMPro?-db=nvpassoc.fp5&-format=nvp_search_results.htm&-lay=web%20form&-max=20&-skip=' + str(skip) + '&-findall='
        print next_page
    except IndexError as e:
        print e
        break


# print list_of_rows

outfile = open("./trialpage.csv","wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

You could take bigger chunks since you are not limited by screen view and I think it would work faster. Try max=200, and then step increments by 200

Comment: Thanks @joel. Once it hits, the last page, the code still keeps looping and the last page is repeated forever. Anyway in which I can set the max skip to stop?

Comment: I noticed that myself.  I suggest you access the page manually, and figure out something that would trigger an end to your collection.  See my edit to code

Comment: Great, that works. However, each of the records that the script is scraping is basically repeated 7 times each (which is the number of columns in this exercise).

Comment: for that, look at what your beautiful soup code is doing.

Comment: I noticed I botched some of your indenting.  I fixed that on `list_of_rows.append(..)` by outdenting.  Try it again

Comment: Thanks a ton joel! This has been really helpful :). Time to start digging into more python and html!